# Using "*" inside python

Tags: python

I am supposed to use find out how to use "*" to sum up several values.
For example:

```
sum_all(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  
15
sum_all(49, 51)  
100
```

Given a general function like :

```
def sum_all(*args)
```

I am unsure how to implement the * within the code.

Comment: `*args` is a list, `**kwargs` a dictionary. Just proceed as you would with any of them.

Comment: @ikaros45: Technically it's a `tuple` since it doesn't support item assignment.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: Sir, you are damn right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat the passed in variable as an iterable.

```
sum_nums = 0
for val in args:
    sum_nums += val
```

A good read would be the top answer in [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131403/what-is-the-name-of-in-python) question.

Answer (score 3):

```
def sum_all(*args):
    total = 0
    for arg in args:
        total += sum(arg)
    return total
```

To be different from the others which i think posted at the same time as me, i'll explain and come up with another solution.

When doing `*args` you can look at it this way:

```
def sum_all([arg1, arg2, arg3, ...]):
```

Which would tedious to code and since you don't know how many parameters are given, you do `*args` instead, which dynamically takes a "endless" amount of arguments in a list format.

### The most neat way i can think of:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    return sum(sum(arg) for arg in args)
```

This assumes the input is something along the lines of:

```
sum_all([1,2,3], [5,5], [10,10])
```

If not just skip one of the sums:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

Comment: `sum(arg for arg in args)` is just an verboser and way more innefficient version of just `sum(args)`

Comment: @ikaros45 yepp, i'm aware.. but m.wasowski beat me to it so didn't feel like changing the answer, but i will

Comment: One question for the last code:
when you use def sum_all(*args): return sum(args), why could you use args without the *?

Answer (score 2):

```
def sum_all(*args):
    s = 0
    for n in args:
       s = s + n
    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try as,

```
 def sum_all(*args):
    return sum([i for i in args])
```

Answer (score 1):

In short:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

`*args` represent here a sequence of positional arguments, that you can later iterate over. Fortunately, builtin `sum()` takes single iterable as argument, so you can just pass it there.

More info you can find in docs:
http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another

Answer (score 1):

Just 2 lines of code :)

```
def sum_all(*args):
    return (sum(args[0])
```